# DXA Model Service : Returns complete data

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

We are on a 8.5 platform with DXA 2.0. 
Due to the client requirements, we are not using the default navigation for creating menus/footers, instead we have a custom schema for both these which are fairly complex. 
In these components we are adding the required components as internal links at 3rd level of the menu schema. When we are fetching the data from model service, it is returning almost the complete website data with every request.

It is basically getting all the directly linked or indirectly components along with every detail of each, whereas we just need the link ("url") for those linked components.

Since these are in menu and footer, this huge information is flowing with every request and slowing down our servers and websites. Even the though the 2nd request should have been faster (assuming the 1st time, it gets cached), it doesn't seem to be happening

Question: Is this an expected behavior or are we missing some obvious configuration? If yes, shouldn't the 2nd request be faster? We have verified our caching settings which has been set to 1hr.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that linked Components (and Keywords) are expanded in the DXA R2 JSON.

The number of levels that this expansion should happen is configurable (in the “Render Page/Component Content” TBBs).

Furthermore, you can choose for *dynamic expansion* (in the DXA Model Service) by associating the linked Component’s Schema with the “Generate Data Presentation” CT.

BTW: If you are using a custom approach to building the Navigatiom Model: have you considered replacing the “Generate Sitemap” TBB with your own?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Rick. We will verify the settings and update them if needed. Yes, we are already considering that and we do have a different requirement from client on sitemap as well.